# can I use local notification and push notification together in ios?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, localnotification

In my app, is it possible to use both local and push notification together in iOS?

Comment: Yep. They server very different purposes, but you can use both. For documentation, see [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is yes. You can use both in iOS app. Here is a link to WWDC video's:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=517

And here is the doc's with sample codes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

Comment: Thank you for additional links. It shortened annoying research time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Local as well as Push Notification in the same app.